# Why isnt Gitlab asking me for my credentials?

Tags: gitlab

Im new to Gitlab and private/public keys.

I have a project in my local machine with git initialized, and a few commits.

I created a private repo in Gitlab.

I also created a private/public key and added the public key to gitlab.

When i try to push with `git push -u origin --all`  I get this message:

```
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.com (**xxx.xxx.xx**)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:**xxxxxxxxx**.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

If I type yes I get this message:

```
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.com' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Connection closed by **xxxxxxxxxx** port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Then, when i try to push again, i get the same message as the first one.

Since Im the only one attached to the project, shouldn't Gitlab ask me (supposedly the only one who can push to the private repo) for my credentials when i try to push to it and then, and only then, let me push to it?

Besides that, if i unprotect the branch, i can push to it using **--force**. But (and correct me if i'm wrong), if I unprotect the branch, anyone with the url will be able to push to the repository, since gitlab also does not ask for my credentials when I try to push to it using **--force**.

I'm sorry if the question is dumb, I'm just having a hard time trying to figure out how to protect my repo from unauthorized access.

How can I keep the branch protected, and only be allowed to push to it using some type of auth, like gitlab asking me for my credentials?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your ssh-agent is not using the correct key. Add the following configuration to ./ssh/config

```
Host gitlab.com
  Host gitlab.com
  Preferredauthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/path_to_private.key
```

I hope this will fix your issue